# How can I add event listener for an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with how to `addEventLisener` to an object when writing a member function for that object.

I have a class called `Grid` which has a member function `create` that creates a HTML `div` element. Now I want to add an event listener to that `div`, which waits for `click`. Here is the code.

Notice that I have another member function `update` for the Grid.

```
Grid.prototype.create = function(index) {
    var newnode = document.createElement("div");
    newnode.setAttribute("class", "grid");
    newnode.setAttribute("id", "grid" + index);
    newnode.style.width = this.width + "px";
    newnode.style.height = this.height + "px";
    document.getElementById("whole").appendChild(newnode);

    newnode.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (this.live) {
            this.live = false;
        } else {
            this.live = true;
        }
        this.update(index);
    }, false);

    this.update(index);
 };
```

The problem is, `this` represents an `HTML DIV Object` inside the `addEventListener` block , but I need it to be a `Grid Object` so that the `update` function can be called.

**How to solve this problem?** Or is there another way to add listener for an object whenever the `div` that contains it is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a variable that is declared outside the scope of the event handler

```
Grid.prototype.create = function(index) {
    var grid    = this,
        newnode = document.createElement("div");

    newnode.className    = "grid";
    newnode.id           = "grid" + index;
    newnode.style.width  = this.width + "px";
    newnode.style.height = this.height + "px";

    newnode.addEventListener("click", function() {

        grid.live = !grid.live;
        grid.update(index);

    }, false);

    document.getElementById("whole").appendChild(newnode);

    this.update(index);
 };
```